# html alert message on certain image

Tags: jquery, html, image

I recently posted a question with this code and solved it, but now I'm having difficulty with something else. How could I throw an alert if the user tries to click on a image that contains the 'go.gif'? I'm wanting to be able to click and change all other images but if the user tries to click on that one, it should throw an alert and leave it how it is.

```
<table>
 <tr>
<td class='change' id='c1'><img src='images/on.gif'/></td>
<td class='change' id='c2'><img src='images/on.gif'/></td>
<td class='change' id='c3'><img src='images/on.gif'/></td>
<td class='change' id='c4'><img src='images/go.gif'/></td>
<td></td>    
</tr>
</table>
```

and this:

```
$(function() {
$(document).on('click', '.change', function () {
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    img.attr('src', (img.attr('src') == 'images/on.gif' ? 'images/off.gif' : 'images/on.gif'));
});
});
```

EDIT: In fact, is there some way to do it so that all the id's containing that image should be listed. OR if it's easier, any id containing that image should throw an alert if the user clicks on it.

I hope that's easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.change', function () {
        var img = $(this).find('img').not('[src$=go.gif]');
        img.attr('src', (img.attr('src') == 'images/on.gif' ? 'images/off.gif' : 'images/on.gif'));
    });
});

$('table td img[src$=go.gif]').click(function () {
    alert('Something that you like');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/micka/Ngs3T/

check out this page for nice jquery selection practices: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_to_Get_Anything_You_Want

Comment: This answer is right. I misunderstood the question. My bad for not reading the question correctly.